# Is there an alternative to SVCUTIL.EXE for generating WCF Web service proxies?

Tags: wcf, proxy

Am I missing something or is there truly no alternative (yet, I hope) to SVCUTIL.EXE for generating WCF Web service proxies?

Answer (score 3):

I would strongly suggest that you look through the auto generated configurations before just using them, the autogenerated stuff is full of garbage.
Try looking at this article by Miquel Castro: [WCF the Manual Way... the Right Way](http://www.code-magazine.com/Article.aspx?quickid=0809101)

Comment: +1 for a really interesting link. Where I am currently contracting all the services have been defined manually. This was mainly to stop the problem of multiple coders failing to update the service references.

Answer (score 2):

I usually just use a ChannelFactory for a given interface. Provided the interface has the adequate WCF attributes, it should work fairly well.
Here's a client example for a duplex channel:

```
DuplexChannelFactory<IServerWithCallback> cf = 
        new DuplexChannelFactory<IServerWithCallback>(
            new CallbackImpl(), 
            new NetTcpBinding(), 
            new EndpointAddress("net.tcp://localhost:9080/DataService"));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a command-line alternative or standalone GUI then no - I don't know of any.

However, if you're wondering about usage while developing in VS, VS2008's add service reference is an alternative that can save you some headache.

Comment: Same in VS2015.
And I'm going to go way out on a limb and guess... all the versions between.

Answer (score 1):

Doh. I was reading old docs and just realized that the Add Service Reference does the grunge for you. THank you!